# How to explain words "animated suit"?

Tags: word-meaning

How do you understand words "animated suit"?
Deadpool in trailer asks: "Please, don't make my superhero suit green or animated". How to say that phrase in other words?

Trailer is here: [link](https://youtu.be/FyKWUTwSYAs?t=33s)

Comment: Have you checked its dictionary entry? How would you interpret it?

Comment: @user2684291 there are many options in dictionary and I'm unable to choose the correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Animated" refers to computer animation/CGI Effects. More specifically this is an instance of Deadpool breaking the fourth wall - Ryan Reynolds, who portrayed Deadpool in the movie, had also played Hal Jordan in the much hated Green Lantern movie where his superhero costume was computer-generated imagery, or more colloquial, computer "animated" (and also green).

Comment: Good idea! Is it just your thoughts, or maybe you have heard or read about that? I've heard another explanation

Comment: No official source, but I know at least that I'm not the only one who thought of this (it's an accepted answer somewhere in scifi.stackexchange.com). I cannot even think of another explanation.

Comment: Yes, I found that question and answer: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/114782/was-deadpool-always-aware-of-the-fourth-wall/114800#114800

Comment: Yea, that was hilarious esp. the part when he was going to fight Francis going, "cue the music". :)

Comment: @Yuri when he said "cue the music", he was talking with movie creators, so it is a breaking of the fourth wall. But his phrase about a suit was addressed to doctors, so, it is not a breaking of the fourth wall.  It's just a reference and gag

Comment: Wow great thanks, I liked the phrase 'the forth wall'.